# MariaDB/MySQL TDE extract/recover key from running server, when keyfile is lost?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, encryption

If I have a MariaDB Server encrypted with the [File Key Management Encryption Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/) (TDE / Transparent Data Encryption), is it somehow possible to extract the key from the running server?
To my understanding, the key is only required on startup, but now the file might be lost and I was wondering if there is a way to recover it from the running server?